# Access the members of base classes with multiple inheritance and templates

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance

I wish to be able to read the first four integers from a file, and be able to retrieve them by their names: N,H,C,W.
for example:

```
//some_file.mat: {10,20,30,40.....}
data_format.read_header<N,C,W,H>(some_file.mat);
cout << data_format.getN(); // prints the first read integer: 10
cout << data_format.getH(); // prints the fourth read integer: 40

data_format.read_header<C,N,H,W>(some_file.mat);
cout << data_format.getN(); // prints the second read integer: 20
cout << data_format.getH(); // prints the fourth read integer: 30
```

The following code, tries to achieve this using multiple inheritance and templates:

```
struct N{ int val; };
struct C{ int val; };
struct H{ int val; };
struct W{ int val; };

struct DataFormat : N, C, H, W
{
    template<class T1, class T2, class T3, class T4>
    bool read_header(FILE* p_file)
    {
        int res = 0;
        res += fread(&T1::val, sizeof(int), 1, p_file); //doesn't compile
        res += fread(&T2::val, sizeof(int), 1, p_file); //doesn't compile
        res += fread(&T3::val, sizeof(int), 1, p_file); //doesn't compile
        res += fread(&T4::val, sizeof(int), 1, p_file); //doesn't compile
        return (res != 0);
    }
    int getN(){ return N::val; }
    int getC(){ return C::val; }
    int getH(){ return H::val; }
    int getW(){ return W::val; }
};


static void foo(){

    DataFormat data_format;
    FILE* some_file;
    data_format.read_header<N, W, H, C>(some_file);
}
```

I get the next compiler error message: on all lines starting with `res+=fread...`

> error C2664: 'size_t fread(void *,size_t,size_t,FILE *)' : cannot
>   convert argument 1 from 'int N::* ' to 'void *'

Why?
Any suggestions for a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&T1::val` will return a *member pointer* (i.e. sth like `N::*`), not a pointer to the variable (i.e. `int*`) as you expected.

You could add `this` qualifier to access member variables in base class, like:

```
res += fread(&this->T1::val, sizeof(int), 1, p_file);
res += fread(&this->T2::val, sizeof(int), 1, p_file);
res += fread(&this->T3::val, sizeof(int), 1, p_file);
res += fread(&this->T4::val, sizeof(int), 1, p_file);
```